# Heroku hobby-dev PG limit?

Tags: heroku

Docs say that I can have 10k rows in my DB. After pg:info I have

```
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE_URL (DATABASE_URL)
Plan:        Hobby-dev
Status:      Available
Connections: 0/20
PG Version:  9.3.6
Created:     2015-04-16 11:06 UTC
Data Size:   16.7 MB
Tables:      16
Rows:        40302/10000 (Above limits, access disruption imminent)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
Rollback:    Unsupported
```

I still can add something to my DB, so how this limit works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a hard limit; you can go above it. However, eventually (usually within a day of exceeding the limit) you will receive an email that you are over the limit, and if you don't delete the excess rows, your web app may be suspended.